# Android tools not showing in eclipse after update

Tags: android, eclipse

Don't know if this is the right place to write but I ran into some problems with Eclipse and Android SDK.

I installed some updates in Eclipse through Help/Check for updates, including the Android plugin or what it's called.

So after the installation I restarted the eclipse and now everything is gone! I can't create new Android projects, can't run existing ones.

I taught that maybe I will just install this plugin again, but when I copy the google url for the plugin in software window it shows Error - Duplicate location.

It's like everything is gone. When I want to create new project, I even can't create new Java project! I have only these kind of options as shown in picture!

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you have to download ADT again

Comment: I think I will reinstall the Eclipse and will never make these kind of stupid move - update something in Eclipse!

Comment: The problem is that it shows that I hav ADT installed under installed software!

Comment: mmh strange, in that case I would uninstall everything an reinstal ADT from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html, of corse doing a previous back up of your projects